# Hit anchor tag button on loaded web page and hit Ok button with vba

Tags: javascript, jquery, vba, excel

I have below code which loads the web page. 
I want to click on "Advanced Search" anchor tag on loaded web page and then hit OK button thereafter.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveHTml()
Dim str1, str2, str3, str4, str5, str6, str7, URL As String
Dim ie, frm As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim filename As String
Dim FF As Integer
'Dim elems As IHTMLInputTextElement
Dim wb As WebBrowser
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object
Dim Button As Object

'On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
str1 = Sheets("PR_data_with_search").Range("F10").Value
str2 = Sheets("PR_data_with_search").Range("I10").Value

URL = "https://webtac.industrysoftware.automation.com/webpr/webpr.php?objtype=frames" 'for TEST
filename = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Desktop\Test.htm"

Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate URL

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set ie = Nothing
' load next web page
Dim i1 As Integer
Dim txt, p As String, link As String
txt = "Advanced Search"
Do Until link = txt
    i1 = i1 + 1
    p = ie.Document.Links(i1).tostring
    link = Right(p, 6)
Loop
ie.Document.Links(i).Click

ie.Document.getelementsbyname("openedFrom_dateText")(0).Value = str1
ie.Document.getelementsbyname("openedTo_dateText")(0).Value = str2

'Call ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("ok").Item(1).Click
Set Button = ie.Document.getElementById("ok")
Button.Click

Do
Loop While ie.Busy

CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile filename

Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop

FF = FreeFile
Open filename For Output As #FF

With ie.Document.body
    Print #FF, .outerHTML & .innerHTML
End With

Close #FF

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The html code for Advanced Search anchor tag is:

```
<li><a href="javascript:parent.gotoSearch('advanced')">Advanced Search</a></li>
```

and for Ok button on web page is:

```
<input type=button name="ok" id="ok" value=" OK " onClick="onSubmitFunction()">
```

Comment: Why do you `Set ie = Nothing` after the page has loaded?

Comment: Oh, some where I had read about setting it in between. May I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce additional explicit waits and ensure loop until page loaded

```
ie.document.querySelector("a[href='javascript:parent.gotoSearch('advanced')']").Click

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,2) '<== uncomment this for additional wait time. Change 2 to other # of seconds as required.

ie.document.getElementById("ok").Click
```

Alternatively, loop until element is set (probably should add a time-out as well):

```
 Do
    DoEvents
    Dim a As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set a = IE.document.getElementById("ok")
    On Error GoTo 0
 Loop While a Is Nothing
```